# CrossThreadMessagingException WPF OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2012, openfiledialog

I get this exception:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException was unhandled HResult=-2146232832 Message=An exception 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException' occurred
>    Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime
>    StackTrace: at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.Main.ThrowCrossThreadMessageException(String formatString) 
>   InnerException:

When I use this code:

```
    public string ShowOpenFileDialog(string initialPath, string filter = null)
    {
        var dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            InitialDirectory = Directory.Exists(initialPath) ? Path.GetDirectoryName(initialPath) : String.Empty,
            FileName = File.Exists(initialPath) ? Path.GetFileName(initialPath) : String.Empty,
            Filter = filter
        };

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            return dialog.FileName;
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
```

I am not explicitly using multithreading, so what is causing this?  It happens frequently during debugging, but not all the time.  I've changed the method signature about a million times, because I was passing in ref/out parameters and thought they might be the cause.

edit: I'm calling it from the UI Thread. Button in View -> Command in ViewModel -> ShowOpenFileDialog.

Comment: Where are you calling this method?  Is there anything in the debugger/watch window that might call this?

Comment: I'm calling it from the UI Thread. Button in View -> Command in ViewModel -> ShowOpenFileDialog.  I'm not sure what you mean about the debugger/watch window (there are some parts of VS I haven't learned quite yet).

Comment: I've also been experiencing some weird debugger behavior that I do not experience in my work environment on a different computer at home (symbols not loading on launch, source not found, etc).  I'm attempting a VS repair right now in hopes that it may somehow fix these issues.

Comment: At which line do you get the exception? Maybe its helfpull do add your Calling Code, also.

Comment: I actually wrap the calling code in a try-catch, but the exception is unhandled.

Comment: Do you have the `[STAThread]` Annotation on the Main-Method of your application? (FileDialogs can only be used in single-threaded apartment model)

Comment: It's using the default WPF Application class, which, I'm assuming, obscures the main method.  Also, repairing VS didn't do a thing.  However, I seem to have noticed if I do something involving a WCF call before using this method, it doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not still sure why this is happening, I've figured out how to fix in my case.  I have multiple projects in my solution, and I've configured two startup projects (client + server).  When I start both projects with debugging, it appears that the debugger has trouble with that.  So I just switch off debugging for the project that matters least at the moment, so there is only one project for the debugger to handle.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problems (CrossThreadMessagingException) with multiple startup project in Visual Studio 2012.

This problem can be solved in VS 2012, if you assign one project as "Start without debugging".

What the interest, this problem is not apparent in the Visual Studio 2013.